# Sending custom object over socket, always null at the server

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a client (Android application) and a server. I want to send an object from the client to the server. I run the server from Netbeans and the client from Eclipse. The problem is that  the object on the server end is null. I have added the package with the class so that´s existing in both the server project and the client-project.

The client:

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                out.flush();
                in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                if(quiz != null) {
                    Log.e("Name", quiz.getName()); // 
                }

                out.writeObject(quiz);
                out.flush();

                socket.close();
                out.close();
                in.close();
```

The log is writing the name of the quiz, so it is not null. The server is multi threaded and the critical part of the client communicator look like this:

```
Quiz quiz = null;
        try {
            in = null;
            ut = null;
            try {

                in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                ut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                quiz = (Quiz)in.readObject();


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                    server.disconnected(socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }

             if(quiz == null) {
                    System.out.println("Something is wrong");
                }
                socket.close();
                in.close();
                ut.close();
```

The server is printing "Something is wrong", so the object is null. I moved thep package com.example.quiz to the Source package - folder in the server-project, so it should be the same object at both ends. The class of the object is also implementing Serializable.

What can be wrong?

Comment: Maybe you're closing the socket before the data is sent. What happens if you sleep for a few seconds before closing the socket? (This is just a test. Sleeping is not a good permanent solution so don't leave it in)

Comment: Is your Quiz object serializable?

Comment: If Quiz wasn't serializable it would throw an exception

Comment: Thanks immibis, but that didn't solve it. :/

Answer (score 0):

> The server is printing "Something is wrong", so the object is null.

No. The server is printing "something is wrong" so *either* the object is null *or* you caught one of the possible exceptions. The code that uses `quiz` should be inside the `try` block, not after all the `catch` blocks. If you really received `null` from `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` it can only be because you wrote a `null` with `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject().`

Comment: Ok, thank you. My custom object consists of several other custom non serializable objects, so that was the problem.